# React - Detect previous location at top level App component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I need to check for location changes across my app so that I can show a component after the user navigates away from a certain page. The components inside `<Router>` have access to location variables, but how do access location variables at the top level, outside of `<Router>`? Here's some psuedo code for what I'm trying to accomplish -

```
export const App = () => {
  const [showComponent, setShowComponent] = useState(false)  

  useEffect(() => {
    if (/* previous location === x */) {
      setShowComponent(true)
    }
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          ...
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      {showComponent && <Component />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really access them outside the router (at least not through the library...).  Just move the dependency up the tree.  Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-rosalind-ol9qw?file=/src/index.js):

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

App.js

```
import { withRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function App({ history, location }) {
  console.log(history, location);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Switch>{/* Add routes here */}</Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```